# Using reflection in net core packages targeting several frameworks

Tags: reflection, nuget-package, .net-core

I am developing a library(`nupkg`) in *.net core* targeting both `net45` and `netstandard1.3` and at some point I need to use reflection so my `project.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.1.3",
  "dependencies": {
       common-dependencies
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net45": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Reflection": "4.0.0.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "NLog": "4.3.5",
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.4"
      }
    },
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50",
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
        "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.1.0",
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.2",
        "NLog": "4.4.0-*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Most of the times after a mere `install-package my-package` everything works like a charm, however a couple of times I get this error on installing:

> install-package : Failed to add reference. The package 'my-Package' tried to add a framework reference to 'System.Reflection' which was not found in the GAC. This is possibly a bug in the 
>   package. Please contact the package owners for assistance.

I've found a workaround, which is to `uninstall-package` every other package on the project I want to install my package. This is very odd and undesired behavior I think.

I do have noticed however that on some of those project had different versions of `Newtonsoft.Json` installed on different projects. This is a warning I also get when installation fails:

> Install failed. Rolling back...
>   Package 'my-package : Newtonsoft.Json [6.0.4, ), NLog [4.3.5, )' does not exist in project 'Target.Project'

I have no idea what could be going on here, and the fact that it happens randomly and the workaround to fix it don't help much.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Reflection` is a reference assembly, but not a runtime assembly. So, you need to use it when building your code, but not reference it from your built assembly.

To do that, specify `"type": "build"`, e.g.:

```json
"frameworkAssemblies": {
  "System.Reflection": { "type": "build" }
}
```

Comment: sorry for taking so long to mark it as right ;). Thanks a lot